# How to add custom rules to spaCy tokenizer to break down HTML in single tokens?

Tags: python, parsing, spacy

I know there are a lot of resources out there for this problem, but I could not get spaCy to do exactly what I want.

I would like to add rules to my spaCy tokenizer so that HTML tags (such as `<br/>` etc...) in my text would be a single token.

I am right now using the "merge_noun_chunks" pipe, so I get tokens like this one:
`"documentation<br/>The Observatory Safety System"` (this is a single token)

I would like to add a rule so that this would get split into 3 tokens:
`"documentation", "<br/>", "The Observatory Safety System"`
I've looked up a lot of resources: [here](http://www.longest.io/2018/01/27/spacy-custom-tokenization.html), [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549856/tokenizing-an-html-document). But I couldn't get that to work in my case

I have tried this:

```
    
    infix_re = re.compile(r'''<[\w+]\/>''')
    prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
    suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=prefix_re.search,
                                suffix_search=suffix_re.search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=None)
```

I am not sure I understand exactly what changing the infix does. Should I also remove `<` from prefixes [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52595182/13020673)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this seems to involve making the tokenizer both

1. break up tokens containing a tag without whitespace, and
2. "lump" tag-like sequences as single tokens.

To split up tokens like the one in your example, you can modify the tokenizer infixes (in [the manner described here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3673)):

```
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes + [r'([><])']
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes).finditer
```

To ensure tags are regarded as single tokens, you can use "special cases" (see [the tokenizer overview](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#annotations-token) or the [method docs](https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer#add_special_case)). You would add special cases for opened, closed and empty tags, e.g.:

```
# open and close
for tagName in "html body i br p".split():
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(f"<{tagName}>", [{ORTH: f"<{tagName}>"}])    
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(f"</{tagName}>", [{ORTH: f"</{tagName}>"}])    

# empty
for tagName in "br p".split():
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(f"<{tagName}/>", [{ORTH: f"<{tagName}/>"}])
```

Taken together:

```
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import ORTH

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes + [r'([><])']
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes).finditer

for tagName in "html body i br p".split():
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(f"<{tagName}>", [{ORTH: f"<{tagName}>"}])    
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(f"</{tagName}>", [{ORTH: f"</{tagName}>"}])    

for tagName in "br p".split():
    nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(f"<{tagName}/>", [{ORTH: f"<{tagName}/>"}])
```

This seems to yield the expected result. E.g., applying ...

```
text = """<body>documentation<br/>The Observatory <p> Safety </p> System</body>"""
print("Tokenized:")
for t in nlp(text):
    print(t)
```

... will print the tag in its entirety and on its own:

```
# ... snip
documentation
<br/>
The
# ... snip
```

I found [the tokenizer's explain method](https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer#explain) quite helpful in this context. It gives you a breakdown of what was tokenized why.